# Preloaded database with Realm Swift

Tags: swift, database, error-handling, realm

I'm having a little trouble in getting PreLoaded data to work. At first, here is code:

```
 if  firstRun  {
            userDefaults.set(1, forKey: "dayCount")
            userDefaults.set(dateFormatter.string(from: date), forKey: "date")

            let newPath = defaultPath.deletingLastPathComponent()
            let v0Path = bundleURL("default")
            do {
                //try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultPath)
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: v0Path!, to:defaultPath)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } ...
```

v0Path:

> file:///Users/dimasalbuquerque/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7FE635BA-AA7A-4241-AF3B-88AD60693AE7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B6739B92-B7D8-4DD8-9DA8-CD9BBD84B109/Example.app/default.realm

defaultPath:

> file:///Users/dimasalbuquerque/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7FE635BA-AA7A-4241-AF3B-88AD60693AE7/data/Containers/Data/Application/A86C4337-9006-497C-A688-AD781F49EF04/Documents/default.realm

I followed this guide: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Migration/AppDelegate.swift

Problem is that when the program is running by the first time, it executes the code correctly, but when I try to access  realm database, it says it's empty. Although when I open the app for the second time, it works, the data is there. It's already over 1 week that I'm trying to solve this, I've searched through all the net but without success.

Here is where Realm is first called:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backward: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var forward: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var background: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var timeBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var favoriteBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var googleAd: GADBannerView!

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let realm = try! Realm()
var currentDate = 1
var time = 0 {
    didSet {
        if time != oldValue {
            randomBackground(time)
        }
    }
}
var dailyMessage: DailyMessagesRealm?
var currentMsg: Message?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let first = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "notFirstRun")
    if !first {
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "notFirstRun")
        reNew()
    }

    let day = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "dayCount")
    currentDate = day
    let empty = realm.objects(DailyMessagesRealm.self).isEmpty
    let dailyMessage = realm.objects(DailyMessagesRealm.self).filter("date == '\(day)'").first
    //*********Error occurs here***********
    self.dailyMessage = dailyMessage!
    self.currentMsg = dailyMessage?.morningMessage
    self.currentMsg = dailyMessage?.morningMessage
    changeMessage((dailyMessage?.morningMessage?.message)!)
    initAds()
    changeBackground("morning1")
    checkFavorite()
} ...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of it, you must be calling `Realm()` somewhere before you're performing your copy operation here.

`default.realm` is only opened when you call `Realm()` for the first time. Once it's open though, it stores cached information about the file in memory, so if you replace it after the fact, you'll end up with unpredictable behavior.

If you absolutely need to do some kind of operation with `Realm()`, you can enclose it in an `@autoreleasepool { }` block to ensure its cached entries in memory are predictably flushed before you do the file copy.

Other than that, I recommended checking your code to ensure you're performing this file copy before touching any instances of `Realm()` pointing at it.

Comment: Hi there, the operation occurs in _didFinishLaunchingWithOptions_ from _AppDelegate.swift_ and I only call Realm within the first controller, that is called _HomeController.swift_, I edited the question to include that code as well.

Comment: Hi! How is the first controller being launched? Is it via a storyboard? If so, storyboards initialize their view controllers before the app delegate is called, which would cause this sort of issue. You need to manually instantiate and present your first view controller at the end of the app delegate method. :)

Comment: Yeah! Exactly, it's via storyboard. I will try that and report you the results!

Comment: I used this code to open the storyboard view that is attached to a tabBarController: 

`let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return true
`

but now, it gives me EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION() on `let realm = try! Realm()`